# Reject a string with only strings in password

Tags: c#, regex

Why is this regular expression not working?

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(password, "(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)"));
```

As you can see the expression contains negative look ahead, so basically if the string starts and ends with alphabets it should reject it. But I get always true no matter what I input. Why is this happening?

Comment: "a string with only strings in password" ... what?

Comment: So you want to reject any string where the first AND the last char are letters and accept all others?

Comment: I think he wants the Regex to *not* match any string that starts with [a-zA-Z] or ends with [a-zA-Z], but the above does match them

Comment: Obligatory password security link: http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: In any case, you seem to have the wrong idea about lookahead assertions.

Comment: Are you sure you want to impose this restriction on your users? "Correct Horse Battery Staple" should be a legit password. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You regex matches nothing, which is not followed by a pure alphanumeric string. So every input matches that. Remember, the lookahead is not part of what is matched - it's just a condition.

Use this to match all inputs that do not start or end with alphanumeric:

```
"^[^a-z](.*[^a-z])?$"
```